# JQuery dom treeview hierarchy problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, treeview

So, I have this html code.

```
<div class="test">
    A
    <div class="test">
     B
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
    C
    <div class="test">
      <div class="test">
        D
      </div>
     E
    </div>
</div>
```

And I am trying to structure the data to something like this using jQuery.

```
[0] = [0] = <div class="test">A</div>
      [1] = <div class="test">B</div>

[1] = [0] = <div class="test">C</div>
      [1] = [0] = <div class="test">C</div>
      [1] = [1] = <div class="test">E</div>
```

But the problem I am facing is that I can't make jQuery ignore the first set of DIVS when its finished parsing (A AND B).

This is how far ive come.

```
getFor($(document).first());

  function getFor($prev) {
    // look for initial foorloop
    var $cur = $prev.find(".class").first();
    if (!$cur.length) {
      return;
    }
    // save it
    collection.push($cur);
    //look for descendants
    // has childreN? then create a new array instead?
    getFor($cur);
    // We found our first hit. go thru nodes
  }
  console.log(collection);
```

I know I am on the right path, but without involving .remove() and start from the $(document), I dont know how to get to the second block of .class...

Thanks in advance

/xgx

Comment: `$('.test').each(function() {...` ?

Comment: That will result in a chronological order from top to bottom. Not what I am looking for.

Comment: Looks to me like you'd get exactly what you want, at least what you should want? A contains B, so getting A means getting it's childnodes as well, there's really no way around that, other than removing the childnodes.

Comment: OOh i see, now I feel kind of stupid, thank you for the answer :)